# How to validate multiple numeric inputs in Shiny and display an error message?

Tags: r, shiny

I have 3 numeric inputs in a Shiny app. These are percentages with a min and max threshold. Obviously the sum should not be greater than 100.

How can I add an error message or notification when the sum of the 3 inputs in greater than 100?

Code below:

```
library(shiny)

# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  numericInput('s1', 'Share 1 (%):', 30, min = 5, max = 55),
  numericInput('s2', 'Share 2 (%):', 30, min = 5, max = 55),
  numericInput('s3', 'Share 3 (%):', 40, min = 5, max = 55),

  textOutput('result')
)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$result <- renderText({
    (input$s1 + input$s2 + input$s3)
  })
}


# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add `validate` like so:

```
library(shiny)

# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  numericInput('s1', 'Share 1 (%):', 30, min = 5, max = 55),
  numericInput('s2', 'Share 2 (%):', 30, min = 5, max = 55),
  numericInput('s3', 'Share 3 (%):', 40, min = 5, max = 55),

  textOutput('result')
)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$result <- renderText({
    out <- input$s1 + input$s2 + input$s3
    validate(
      need(out <= 100, "The sum can't be over 100")
    )
    out
  })
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```